# Refill Ether to account after token transfer

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, tokens

During token creation and token transfer some ethers are used as gas. What is the most efficient way to refill an account with the same amount of ether? So that it doesn't run out of funds(ether). I'm using a web3 version-1. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

when creating transactions, you can adjust gasLimit through option.

And Solidity offers the following keywords.

```
msg.gas
msg.gasprice
```

gas(Transaction fee)= UsedGas * gasPrice = (GasLimit - msg.gas) * gasPrice

Comment: To find UsedGas [eth.getTransactionReceipt](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#gettransactionreceipt) can be used.